# Don't end up falling for the nonsense

Tags: riddle

Hold on just a bit
I need to talk to Lee

> About a test for my Iq
>   That suited me to a T
>   Somehow I got a 6
>   When I should have got zt

Now, if your brain's too tiny
I'll give the riddle a curl

> When I was just 2
>   I played for an fc
>   And won 20 games
>   By the time I had turned 3

Warning:

> When you figure this out, you'll wish you'd heeded my warning

Comment: First line ends with a capital `i` and lowercase q, yes? Not an `L`

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes. This is easily visible if you click "edit".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I go to

> bit.ly ("bit" and "Lee" at the end of the first two lines) and add IqT6zt, I get [rickrolled](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

but

> if I go to tiny url ("tiny" and "curl" at the end of the next two lines) and add 2fcgames3, I get rickrolled again!

Comment: You basically have it.  But why did you change your algorithm from the first to the second?

Comment: @Kevin OK, fixed. For some reason, I didn't think that would work.